# StreamTask numbering - what does numbers signify?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am learning Kafka Stream and got some basic idea of it. Now, trying to understand about the work allocation, and found this [link](https://medium.com/@andy.bryant/kafka-streams-work-allocation-4f31c24753cc).

In that link, I see various `Tasks` like: `Task 0_0` , `Task 1_1` etc.

1. Does `Task ..` are same as `StreamTasks`?
2. What does these numbers signify? `1_1 0_0`.

Comment: How many partitions do your input topics have? Have you tried printing out the Topology?

Comment: @cricket_007: I am trying to understand the concept. To be specific, it is 2 inputs topics, and each topic have 25 partitions.

Comment: @cricket_007: Any inputs you can provide?

Comment: What does the Topology look like?

Comment: @cricket_007: It is a linear topology; 5 processors chain.

Comment: @cricket_007: I think the convention is: subtopology_KafkaPartitionNumber; and since in my case I have only one topology (=0) and so taskId's would be : `0_0, 0_1 , 0_2 .. till 0_23`. Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: Makes sense to me, based on your comments. Though 24 if you had 25 partitions

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of tasks in Kafka Streams: `StreamTasks` and `StandbyTasks`. In your context from above, task is the same as StreamTask.

**About the numbering:** A Kafka Streams `Topology` consists of sub-topologies (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#stream-partitions-and-tasks). Each sub-topology is executed in parallel based on the number of input topic partitions. Hence, for each sub-topology and topic partition a task is created. The numbering (called the "task-id") is `<sub-topology-id>_<partition-number>`.